# Warn when a postgres procedure is returning a setof table result with an incorrect column order

Tags: postgresql

If procedure is defined to return a setof table type, what can I do to ensure that columns from the procedure are being returned in the correct order.

Here is an example of the problem

https://dbfiddle.uk/AzJ5gPa7

The following function makes an assumption about the column order in the return table type of `business_user_group`

```sql
create or replace function organisation_groups(
    organisation_id varchar
) returns setof business_user_group as $$
  select
    business_user_group.organisation_id,
    business_user_group.group_id,
    business_user_group.business_user_id
  from business_user_group
  where business_user_group.organisation_id = organisation_groups.organisation_id;
$$ language sql stable;
```

If the column order is different for the table type `business_user_group` between deployed environments this becomes a real footgun.

DB diffing tools often miss column order, which doesn't help matters here.

What can be done to prevent this ?

Comment: Don’t use setof. You can return a table definition instead

Comment: Same thing happens if I mess up the column order in the select query.

Comment: I suggest the issue is not with the order of columns returned, but with how your app accesses them. In a RDBMS the order of columns is irreverent as they are/should be **accessed by name not position**. I suspect you are using an positional index (i.e resultset[1], etc) instead of resultset.column_name. Use resultset.column_name then the order of the columns does not matter

Comment: No that's not the issue, try the dbfiddle above or here https://dbfiddle.uk/DbvhmNUg, you'll see a query on the result has the values within the wrong column headings.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the select list in the query. When selecting into a list of variables in a PL/pgSQL procedure, the general recommendation is to explicitly enumerate the columns instead of using `SELECT *`. Barring programmer error, enumerating the columns ensures that the order is compatible between the select list and the variables regardless of column order in the table.

Your situation requires the opposite approach; i.e., use `SELECT *` to ensure that the returned data is consistent with the table's column order. Because the column order for both the type associated with the table and `SELECT *` are fully dependent on the table's column order, it is guaranteed that the order will match. This approach also reduces the amount of code maintenance required when columns are added, dropped, or renamed.

In a PL/pgSQL procedure when a query selects into a variable declared as the row type of the table, then the `SELECT *` approach should also be preferred.

Comment: Thanks yes I noticed this behavior as well. However a select * doesn't work unless you are selecting from the same table type, which is often not possible in a non trivial implementation. Demonstrated here https://dbfiddle.uk/FyQINxmN

Comment: A possible solution in those cases could be to use a PL/pgSQL stored procedure instead of SQL and have it dynamically create the select list in the query to guarantee that the column order is consistent with the table's column order. It's a tradeoff between code complexity and risk from table changes.